# Basic Selenium Java generated from IDE not working

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have generated this script from Selenium IDE. It is working in IDE not in Eclipse : it only runs Firefox 20 and go to Google. But it doesn't search anything.

Update : I replaced setSpeed by Thread.Sleep(3000L)
But I don't know how to cope with error comment "locator strategy"

```
package Selenium;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Selenium {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.fr/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSelenium() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("selenium");
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [setSpeed | 3000 | ]]
    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Selenium - Web Browser Automation")).click();
    // Warning: assertTextPresent may require manual changes
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*What is Selenium[\\s\\S][\\s\\S]*$"));
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The IDE source is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.google.fr/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>selenium</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>setSpeed</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>btnG</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Selenium - Web Browser Automation</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>What is Selenium?</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing when trying to run it in eclipse ?

Comment: What version of selenium jar are yuo using ?

Comment: I am using latest version 2.32.0 for both selenium java and selenium server java

Comment: @Makky no error in Eclipse, it just pauses forever. Only when I close Firefox does it says <terminated>.

Comment: I tried it. Google search work for me. Do you get some exception?

Comment: The "setSpeed" error is because not all the IDE commands are 'convertible', so I would use the time wisely to work it out for yourself - simply Google "WebDriver set speed"...as for your actual problem, this is not enough information. To begin with, does it type anything in the search box? I'd also advise you try your first test against something **not** Google.

Comment: Can you show us what your project pom.xml looks like by posting it on a Gist?

Answer (score 1):

This could be sometimes because of using an old selenium jar

Download the latest standalone jar from `http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list`

Try with new library and see if that works.

Comment: I'm using 2.32.00 aren't there latest version ?

Comment: Is your firefox using latest versino ?

Comment: Well it would be a huge bug since it's very basic stuff but thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `testSelenium` method, it types the text into the search field but never presses the *Recherche Google* search button. That step was there in your IDE script:

```
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>btnG</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

It should have been extracted as something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba")).click();
```

Did you remove it from the script in Eclipse for some reason?